# Why is FormData null value converted to "null" when send to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, axios

I have this sample JavaScript:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.set('mode_id', '');
data.set('start', null);
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/test',
    data: data,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

This is the controller endpoint in Laravel:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    \Debugbar::info($request->all());

    $request->validate([
        'start'        =>  'required',
        'mode_id'      =>  'required',
    ]);
```

To my surprise, the validation for parameter `mode_id` failed, but not for parameter `start`.

From Debugbar, I find that `start` value is a string `"null"`.

```
[
  "mode_id" => null
  "start" => "null"
]
```

Why and where is FormData null converted to "null"?

If I do a PHPUNIT test

```
$response = $this->->post('/test', [
        'mode_id' => '',
        'start' => null,
 ]);
```

Both parameter `mode_id` and `start` fail in validation, as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I found it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set:

> formData.set(name, value);
>
> Parameters
>
> name
>
> ```
> The name of the field whose data is contained in value.
> ```
>
> value
>
> ```
> The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses
> such as File). 
> If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.
> ```

In other words, one cannot set `null` as a value with FormData. I have to catch on the FrontEnd a null value, replace it by an empty string and Laravels Middleware `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` will convert this back to `null`.

Comment: Alternatively you can remove the field from formData and not send it. In Symfony the Request object (which AFAIK is also used in Laravel) will convert it to NULL. This way you don't need to implement "extra logic" on the API. Instead the Client(s) have to take care.